# Adding the difference between dates with constant unit

Tags: java, arrays, unit-testing, date

I Need to keep start Start date constant for first iteration and add end date with unit,  and iteration should happen until start date is before end data.

**Example :**

Difference between Start date (1/1/2015) and end date (12/31/2015) is 12 months

and unit is 4 months

then I should get

```
Contract    Start date      End date
1           1/1/2015        4/31/2015
2           5/1/2015        8/31/2015
3           9/1/2015        12/31/2015
```

**CODE** I've tried:

```
 private void contractDetails(List<PolicyPeriodFormulaType> policyPeriod ){


     for (PolicyPeriodFormulaType policyPeriodFormulaType : policyPeriod) {
         Date effectiveDateFrom = policyPeriodFormulaType.getEffectivePeriod().getEffectiveFrom();
         Date effectiveDateTo = policyPeriodFormulaType.getEffectivePeriod().getEffectiveTo();
         Instant effectiveFrom = effectiveDateFrom.toInstant();
         ZonedDateTime zdt = effectiveFrom.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
         LocalDate fromDate = zdt.toLocalDate();

         Instant effectiveTo = effectiveDateTo.toInstant();
         ZonedDateTime zdt1 = effectiveTo.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
         LocalDate toDate = zdt.toLocalDate();



         int unit = policyPeriodFormulaType.getUnits();
         String unitMeasurement = policyPeriodFormulaType.getUnitOfMeasurement();
         Period p = Period.between(fromDate,toDate);
         int months = p.getMonths();
         int years = p.getYears();
         if(unitMeasurement.equalsIgnoreCase("Month")){
             months = months+(years*12);
         }
         int duration = months/unit; // 12/4 = 3
         int i =0;
         while(fromDate.isBefore(toDate)){
             fromDate=fromDate;
             toDate=fromDate.plusMonths(unit);
             fromDate=toDate.plusMonths(unit);
         }


    }



 }
```

Comment: @mikecat_mixc, can you pls tell me where am I going wrong

Comment: What do you mean by "you should get" the table you say you should get?  Your code doesn't output anything, so I don't know how you plan to "get" that table.  If you're just talking about that the values of certain variables at certain points, you haven't told us **which** variables at **which** points.

Comment: I should get means, the expected output should be like that above table.

Comment: yes, I agree my code does not return anything as it is incomplete. I would be thankful if you can tell me the logic to accomplish it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, you should be using either Java 8's Date/Time API or Joda-Time in some form or another, for example...

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.parse("01/01/2015", dtf);
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.parse("12/31/2015", dtf);

LocalDate date = startDate;

Period period = Period.parse("P4M");
// or 
//Period period = Period.ofMonths(4);
// or 
//Period period = Period.of(0, 4, 0);

while (date.isBefore(endDate)) {
    LocalDate to = date.plus(period);
    System.out.println(dtf.format(date) + " - " + dtf.format(to.minusDays(1)));
    date = to;
}
```

which prints

```
01/01/2015 - 04/30/2015
05/01/2015 - 08/31/2015
09/01/2015 - 12/31/2015
```

From that, it wouldn't too hard a stretch to create a container class (ie a `Contract` style class) to contain the to-from values. You could then use `Comparable` or a `Comparator` to keep them sorted in some kind of `List` or array